# PHP: Why does @var $foo Class work and @var $this->foo Class not?

Tags: php, annotations, phpstorm, phpdoc

Why does this work:

```
/* @var $foo ClassName */
$foo->someFunction();
```

but this one not:

```
/* @var $this->foo ClassName */
$this->foo->someFunction();
```

---

Here's the complete setup:

```
abstract class Bar
{
  $foo = null;
}


class Cool
{
  // some function sets $this->foo

  public function doSthWithFoo() // does not work
  {
    /* @var $this->foo ClassName */
    $this->foo->someFunction();
  }

  public function doSthWithFoo2() // works just fine
  {
    $test = $this->foo
    /* @var $test ClassName */
    $test->someFunction();
  }
}
```

Another approach would be to define the $foo variable in the new class again:

```
class Cool
{
  /* @var $foo ClassName */
  $foo = null;

  // ...
}
```

Of cource the PHP code is executed properly, but the PHPDoc is buggy.

*(PhpStorm 2018.2.2)*

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Docblock the abstract class, this should give you better results

Comment: *"but the PHPDoc is buggy."* It's NOT buggy. You just trying to create your own rules of how PHPDoc should work. But it does NOT work that way -- as simple as that. You cannot typehint specific sub entity using `@var` -- only top level/whole entity. So it's what Dale have said .. or you can try `@property` tag in your `Cool` class.

Comment: @Dale / @LazyOne: Yes, but that's not possible in this case. In this case the abstract class' `$foo` property has no type until a class inherits it and sets its specific type. The intention is to 'force' using the inherited `$foo` property instead of creating lots of different properties... (but as you said that's beyond this question)

@LazyOne: You're right, PHPDoc is not buggy, but it would be kind of awesome if that worked.

Comment: Take a look into phpstorm.meta files, they might not be the solution but I believe they may help somewhat, ill try to get a link for you

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata, I've used them to resolve doctrine classes and entities here https://github.com/phutureproof/stormHelpers/blob/master/src/.phpstorm.meta.php

Comment: @Dale Metadata is not for properties. It's for methods that return different instances based on passed parameters.

Comment: @FloBayer `@property` should help here. Other than that -- maybe it can be solved with interfaces? Your example is too broad, but maybe for real classes it might be enough?

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, `@property` would be an option. The abstract class does already implement an interface ;)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer your question directly as I do not know why that doesn't work but I normally do this to get around the situation

```
<?php

class foo
{
    /** @var SomeClass $foo */
    protected $foo;

    // the rest of the class
}
```

And now you should get the proper code completion for `$this->foo->availableThings()`

Comment: Yup, that'd work.
I think I should adjust the answer, I'm sorry: It's a class which inherits from an abstract class that has its $foo attribute. And of course I could mention it again in the new class, but PHPDoc should understand this, right?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, there are times where I docblock the property, but when using it the function returns some unknown type and code completion is lost.. I have other issues with storm 2018.2.2 but that's beyond this question.

Comment: @FloBayer Is the abstract class properly documented?

Answer (score 1):

I want to try to explain by code below:

```
class Foo
{
    public function myFooFunction()
    {
        return 'this is foo function';
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function myBarFoonction()
    {
        return 'this is bar function';
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->myFooFunction(); //call in Foo object

$bar = new Bar($foo);
echo $bar->myBarFoonction(); // call in Bar object
echo $bar->foo->myFooFunction(); // call in Foo object
```

if you call `$bar->foo` - you must call function in that object

Comment: I think the OP understand how to do it, but is questioning why PHPStorm fails to give proper code completion